# how get list of group or channel Bot (Telegram) is joined?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

My bot is registered in several groups and receives data from them.

How to get list of `group` or `channel` is joined?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you yourself should keep track of your users, groups, channels,... .
whenever you get a new update from server, preserve users, chats, channels data in database.

unfortunately there is no method to get your users, channels, groups via api (yet). even you can't know which users have blocked you, unless you send a message to them and get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get those info as you get the chatID of users.

Comment: Where do I get the ChatId?